# Scipy.signal.dimpulse(system): how to translate a StateSpace to a "system"?

Tags: discrete-signals, python, finite-impulse-response, state-space, scipy

The command `scipy.signal.dimpulse(system, x0=None, t=None, n=None)` does not seem to accept a scipy `StateSpace` as an input to its `system` parameter.

Here is my code, and the error. The goal is to generate a series of k-th order Laguerre basis functions.

```
k=5
num_points=100
alpha = 0.01

# create sys1
nn = np.sqrt(1-alpha**2)
n1 = [0,nn]
p1 = [1,-alpha]
sys1 = control.tf2ss(n1, p1)

# create sys0
n0 = [-alpha, 1]
p0 = [1,-alpha]
sys0 = control.tf2ss(n0, p0) #type(sys0) is an "instance", not a "StateSpace"

# create k-th order series
for i in range(2, k):
    result_sys = control.matlab.series(sys0, sys1)

# generate discrete impulse response

result_lti = result_sys.returnScipySignalLti() #(maybe Lti format will work as input...no.)

y1 = scipy.signal.dimpulse(result_sys,x0=1,n=num_points+1)
```

The last command gives this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-a569a95625b6>", line 55, in <module>
    y1 = scipy.signal.dimpulse(result_sys,x0=1,n=num_points+1)

  File "/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/scipy/signal/dltisys.py", line 173, in dimpulse
    A, B, C, D, dt = _system_to_statespace(system)

  File "/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/scipy/signal/dltisys.py", line 20, in _system_to_statespace
    if len(system) == 3:

AttributeError: StateSpace instance has no attribute '__len__
```

Also, the `control.tf2ss` command returns an 'instance', not a 'StateSpace', which seems unusual.

**How can I translate the outputs from [`control.tf2ss`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.tf2ss.html#scipy.signal.tf2ss) and `control.matlab.series` into acceptable input formats to the [`scipy.signal.dimpulse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.dimpulse.html#scipy.signal.dimpulse) system?**

Thank you!